# Describe the algorithm of currency conversion

Tags: java, algorithm, converters, currency, pseudocode

CurrencyConversion that offers the user the choice of converting US Dollars into British Pounds or the other way around. (You may assume that 1 US Dollar = 1.64 Pounds.)

```
// Import scanner 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoneyConversion {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // Declare variable
        final double RATE  = 1.64;

        // Declare currency 
        double dollar;
        double Pounds;

        // Call scanner from keyBoard
        Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask user to enter the amount of pounds 
        System.out.print("Please write number of pounds");

        // Read the value into variable 
        Pounds = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();

        // Write the method for currency conversion
        dollar = Pounds * RATE;

        System.out.println("The number of dollars is "  +  dollar);

    } // End of main


} // End currency conversion
```

Answer (score 0):

Make different classes for different currency conversions as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please write number of pounds");
        System.out.println("The number of dollar is "  +  convertToDollar(fromKeyboard.nextDouble()));
    }    

public static double convertToDollar(double pound){
        double rate  = 1.64;
        double Pounds;
        return( pound * rate);
    }
```